# How Can I Increase The Speed Of My MAXIF Formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, maxifs

I would like to increase the speed of my MAXIF function. Not sure if there is a simpler way to write this, but I have the following formula:

```
=MAX(IF('DH'!$D$1:$D$1048573=$A4,IF('DH'!$N$1:$N$1048573="Proactive",'DH'!$A$1:$A$1048573," ")))
```

Currently this formula is being applied to 2500 cells and slows the workbook down significantly.

I'm thinking maybe an array may assist with this formula.

Comment: what version do you have?

Comment: If you have Office 365 the use MAXIFS: `=MAXIFS('DH'!$A:$A,'DH'!$D:$D,$A4,'DH'!$N:$N,"Proactive")`  If not you need to limit the number of rows to the largest you expect the dataset to become: `=MAX(IF('DH'!$D$1:$D$5000=$A4,IF('DH'!$N$1:$N$5000="Proactive",'DH'!$A$1:$A$5000,"")))`  
`